# Wordpress Slider loading wrong in Safari

Tags: css, slider, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a website that features a image slider below the main menu. I am utilizing the Revolution Slider to display content due to its compatibility support. The slider is not loading correctly in Safari. Instead of displaying inline with the other elements it pops out and loads partially on the upper left hand corner. You can see the effects here. http://mogolianasiareach.com/. This problem is unique to Safari and doesn't show up in any other browsers. I am using the standard embed code placed within the header.php file but it renders wrong.

```
 <?php putRevSlider("mar_slider","homepage") ?>
```

Any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Like you two, I too found Safari rendering the page wrong.  In my case totally different slider, (Advanced Post Slider).  Same issue.

As I design Wordpress sites for a living I found this problem perplexing at the least.  Safari version was not an issue, as it happened in both 4.0.2 thru 5.0.6 that I tested.  Site is fine in FFx, Chrome, have not checked IE.

The "cache" advice above led me to concluded that css indeed needs to be excluded from cache plugin settings.  I added "style.css" to my excluded files and "voila", problem gone.

Thanks for the clues,

Doug

Answer (score 0):

I surprisingly came across the same issue.  Everything worked fine in Chrome, but in Safari any of my sliders would load in the top left corner, not in their respective inline elements.

My situation was very unique and judging by the fact that you were the only other person online I could find who ran into this issue, I'm wondering if we are both in the same unique situation.

For me, I narrowed it down to another plugin which was causing the conflict.  In my case, it was "W3 Total Cache", more specifically, the "Minify" module.

When I minified the CSS, for some reason it introduced a conflict.  Adding the file "/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" to the "Never minify the following CSS files:" section in the settings caused my slider to begin functioning properly again.

If you're also using W3 Total Cache, then I would start there.  Otherwise, I would suggest disabling plugins to see if you can track down the culprit causing the conflict.

Best of luck!

Andy